# Search for multiple files and copy them into the same directory

Tags: macos, search, terminal, grep, copy

I'm working on a mac, and have an excel spreadsheet with a list of around 400 file names. They are all on my hard disc somewhere, but could be anywhere within a large archive directory. Ideally I'd like to avoid having to search for each one individually, copy and then paste them into a new directory together in order to do some downstream analysis.

I was thinking there must be some clever way in terminal to `grep` the file path for a list of file names, then `cp` those files to a new directory of my choice. I don't really know where to start though. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here's a sample of filenames from my spreadsheet:

```
E12_JH_260919_E12_2019-09-26_1.fsa
F01_JH_260919_F01_2019-09-26_1.fsa
F02_JH_260919_F02_2019-09-26_1.fsa
F03_JH_260919_F03_2019-09-26_1.fsa
D10_JH_181019.3_D10_2019-10-18_1.fsa
D11_JH_181019.3_D11_2019-10-18_1.fsa
D12_JH_181019.3_D12_2019-10-18_1.fsa
E01_JH_181019.3_E01_2019-10-18_1.fsa
E02_JH_181019.3_E02_2019-10-18_1.fsa
E03_JH_181019.3_E03_2019-10-18_1.fsa
```

Thanks!

Comment: just to be clear, do you want to find the files mentioned in a file and copy them into a directory?

Comment: Yes exactly, I've updated above, along with a sample of the file names. I want to search for these files in my archive directory, copy them wherever they are, and paste into a new directory of my choosing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` tool for that purpose. Let's say you have a directory like the following:

```
~/archive$ tree
├── ASDF.txt
├── destination_folder
├── DFGH.txt
└── spreadsheet.txt

1 directory, 3 files
```

And a `spreadsheet` like this:

```
~/archive$ cat spreadsheet.txt 
ASDF.txt
DFGH.txt
```

You can read the file line by line, find each file in the current directory, and copy that into another directory:

```
while read name; do
find . $name -maxdepth 0 -type f -exec cp {} ./destination_folder \;
done < spreadsheet.txt
```

And the result should look like this:

```
    ls a
ASDF.txt DFGH.tx
```

Comment: Thanks, I just created this directory structure on my desktop: /Users/michaelflower/Desktop/test_archive. When I try your code in Terminal, the destination_folder sadly remains empty. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: ~/Desktop/test_archive
$ tree
\.
|-- ASDF.txt
|-- DFGH.txt
|-- destination_folder
`-- spreadsheet.txt

Comment: Does it give any error? Do you have file names in your `spreadsheet.txt`? Do they exist in the same directory?

Comment: Thanks, it now seems to be working, though there are a couple of issues. First is it doesn't seem to copy the last file in the list. Second is that if a file is in a subdirectory, the function doesn't find it - my archive has lots of subdirectories, so it's important to be able to search throughout them - is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: sure! play with the maxdepth option. its pretty straightforward

Comment: Thanks, if I change maxdepth to any positive integer (e.g. 1 or 100) it just copies every file in the directory and all subdirectories, regardless of whether they are in the spreadsheet.txt file

Comment: sorry but `-maxdepth` just goes deeper in your directory tree. And this command should copy the last line too. It might be related to your spreadsheet file. and create your `destination_folder` with `mkdir` before executing the command

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry to respond so long after you posted, but I'm still having trouble with this. I've made the destination_folder with mkdir, but when -maxdepth is >0 the command just copies every file in the tree, not just those in the spreadsheet.txt. Is there anything else that could be going wrong with it?